# How to handle mongoDB general operations in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to prepare a general function which will allow me to use any function on any database/collection. I'm not sure im doing this correctly. Here's my function code in node.js:

```
function use_db(db_url, func, ...args) {
    let prom;
    // noinspection JSIgnoredPromiseFromCall
    var lele = MongoClient.connect(db_url, (error, client) => {
        console.log('Connected');
        const db = client.db();

        console.log(db);

        prom = func(db, ...args);
        client.close();
        console.log('Disconnected successfully');
    });
    console.log(lele, 'whaat?');
    return prom;
}
```

I want it to return value `prom` but this happens:

- first output is `console.log(lele, 'whaat?');` which value is `undefined 'whaat?'`
- then `'Connected'`
- and the last is `'Disconnected successfully'`

So obviously `prom` is not defined at this moment

Why output is in this order? Why `console.log(lele, 'whaat?');` runs first?
Any ideas how can I improve this function, so it will use any other function to work on specific mognoDB database?

EDIT://

```
function connectDB(db_url) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        MongoClient.connect(db_url, (error, client) => {
            if (error) return rej(error);
            console.log('Connected');
            const db = client.db();
            return res({
                db,
                client
            });
        });
    });
}

async function use_db(db_url) {
    console.log('Start');
    const {
        db,
        client
    } = await connectDB(db_url);
    console.log('After db connection');

    return [db, client];
}

let temp_list = use_db(db_url);
const db = temp_list[0];
const client = temp_list[1];

let no_user = can_create_user(db, temp_email);

if(no_user) {
    //some code
}
```

How Can I leave active connection to the database and use `db` everytime for other functions? It doesn't wait for promise to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is asynchronous it does not wait for any blocker operation. [check this](https://nodejs.org/ja/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/)

```
function connectDB(db_url) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        MongoClient.connect(db_url, (error, client) => {
            if (error) return rej(error);
            console.log('Connected');
            const db = client.db();
            return res({
                db,
                client
            });
        });
    });
}

async function use_db(db_url, func, ...args) {
    console.log('Start');
    try {
        const {
            db,
            client
        } = await connectDB(db_url);
        console.log('After db connection');
        const prom = func(db, ...args);
        client.close();
        console.log('Disconnected successfully');
        return prom;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I tried it, but it still doesn't seem to be working. I pasted the code above, in the edited question.

Comment: @JavaBoon are you getting any error.

Comment: `(node:12624) DeprecationWarning: Cursor.each is deprecated. Use Cursor.forEach instead.`

   and   


`(node:12624) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.`




Only those two

Comment: it's just a warning, not an error. what's `func` function is doing. check this  it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537880/every-second-run-throws-mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed/55538144#55538144

Comment: In this case it's a reference to `can_create_user `

Comment: Alright, I will try it out (the link)

Comment: I checked it out. I learned that the best way is to leave active connection to the database. I attempted to recreate connection everytime i used it. My progress is updated in editet question

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I just worked around this and merged it all in few functions, where each connects to mongo and then disconnects after. I gave up. Here's a working example of adding a user to my database.

```
function add_user(db_url, name, surname, email, password) {
    MongoClient.connect(db_url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
        const db = client.db();

        db.collection('users').find({email: email}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if(result.length === 0) {
                console.log('Adding new user');
                insert_into_users(db, name, surname, email, sha256(password));
            } else {
                console.log('E-mail already in database');
            }

            client.close();
        });
    });
}

function insert_into_users(db, name, surname, email, password) {
    db.collection('users').insertOne({
        name: name,
        surname: surname,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        liked_films: []
    });
    console.log('New user created');
}
```