# MongoError: topology was destroyed while using with NextJs api

Tags: mongodb, next.js, serverless

I am Using Vercel Serverless funtions to make API Endpoints for Next.js application. I am Using MongoDB to store an Array of Objects.

I have this serverless function

```
// api/global/addlink.js

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");

const client = new MongoClient(process.env.DB_URI, {});

export default async (req, res) => {
  await client.connect();

  const link = JSON.parse(req.body)["link"];
  const query = { _id: ObjectId(JSON.parse(req.body)["_id"]) };

  const result = await client
    .db("myio_guests")
    .collection("link_groups")
    .findOneAndUpdate(query, {
      $push: {
        links: link,
      },
    });

  res.json({
    message: "link added successfully",
    result: result,
  });

  await client.close();
};
```

This function Gives error every 2nd time it runs.

I tried 4 invocations, of the function using fetch post request from my frontend, but only 2 entries are saved those are 1st and 3rd entry.
In case of 2nd and 4th invocation this error occured:

```
2021-01-26T14:14:18.964Z    cae61486-ecb3-4726-aa8c-f8e95d9326ad    WARN    the options [servers] is not supported
2021-01-26T14:14:18.964Z    cae61486-ecb3-4726-aa8c-f8e95d9326ad    WARN    the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
2021-01-26T14:14:18.964Z    cae61486-ecb3-4726-aa8c-f8e95d9326ad    WARN    the options [dbName] is not supported
2021-01-26T14:14:18.964Z    cae61486-ecb3-4726-aa8c-f8e95d9326ad    WARN    the options [srvHost] is not supported
2021-01-26T14:14:18.964Z    cae61486-ecb3-4726-aa8c-f8e95d9326ad    WARN    the options [credentials] is not supported
2021-01-26T14:14:20.203Z    cae61486-ecb3-4726-aa8c-f8e95d9326ad    ERROR   MongoError: topology was destroyed
    at executeCommand (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/db_ops.js:222:21)
    at FindOneAndUpdateOperation.execute (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/find_and_modify.js:107:5)
    at executeOperation (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:77:17)
    at Collection.findOneAndUpdate (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1737:10)
    at module.exports.lt9b.__webpack_exports__.default (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/global/addlink.js:296:75)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js:8:1)
    at async /var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/global/addlink.js:137:387
2021-01-26T14:14:20.203Z    cae61486-ecb3-4726-aa8c-f8e95d9326ad    ERROR   MongoError: topology was destroyed
    at executeCommand (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/db_ops.js:222:21)
    at FindOneAndUpdateOperation.execute (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/find_and_modify.js:107:5)
    at executeOperation (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:77:17)
    at Collection.findOneAndUpdate (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1737:10)
    at module.exports.lt9b.__webpack_exports__.default (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/global/addlink.js:296:75)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js:8:1)
    at async /var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/global/addlink.js:137:387
2021-01-26T14:14:20.204Z    cae61486-ecb3-4726-aa8c-f8e95d9326ad    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MongoError: topology was destroyed","reason":{"errorType":"MongoError","errorMessage":"topology was destroyed","name":"MongoError","stack":["MongoError: topology was destroyed","    at executeCommand (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/db_ops.js:222:21)","    at FindOneAndUpdateOperation.execute (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/find_and_modify.js:107:5)","    at executeOperation (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:77:17)","    at Collection.findOneAndUpdate (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1737:10)","    at module.exports.lt9b.__webpack_exports__.default (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/global/addlink.js:296:75)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)","    at async apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js:8:1)","    at async /var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/global/addlink.js:137:387"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongoError: topology was destroyed","    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:326:22)","    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
```

How Can I solve this Issue on serverless case like this?

Comment: If you run this 4 times but with a 10sec stop between each does it work? my assumption that you're just closing the connection while the function runs

Comment: I have tried using logs to see where the app stops it seems somewhere after second connect. [See](https://i.imgur.com/lU4oO32.png). I know it is a asynchronous but it gone upto that part comparing to the previous or 1st call.

Comment: But Somehow waiting for about 10 min between each request, that thing worked. Can You explain or help me with that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There issue you're having comes from this line:

```
  await client.close();
```

From the docs:

> MongoClient.close() - closes the underlying connector, which in turn closes all open connections. Once called, this Mongo instance can no longer be used.

Meaning when you `close` the client, any other open connections close aswell.
In your case #2 and #4 start running shortly after #1 and #3 (but before they are done), and you close the connection on them while they are still running.

Also from the docs:

> The MongoClient class is designed to be thread safe and shared among threads. Typically you create only 1 instance for a given database cluster and use it across your application.

It would be a best practice to have some state management for your stateless functions (I know), have a connection service that just gives your stateless functions the connection, it would also be easier to manage errors this way.

Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14495975/10770370) and in the [nodejs driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/)

A quick (and very suboptimal) solution to your problem would be to define the connection within the function like so:

```
// remove the definition from here

export default async (req, res) => {
     // and move it here
     const client = new MongoClient(process.env.DB_URI, {});
     await client.connect();

      .....

     await client.close();
};
```

Comment: This example did solved the issue. Thanks.

So also in this case i am closing all the connections. So do i need to cache the connections for better results or that won't be needed? Just asking as suggestion.

Comment: Caching the connection is a first step in the right direction. When you start thinking of monitoring and alerting connection issues you should build a proper service for that.